# SQLAlchemy, concise ways of defining many similar classes/tables

Tags: python, database, oop, sqlalchemy

So I have a lot of tables with a general stucture of

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    uid = Column(Integer, Sequence('Thing_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "something"

class ThingEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thingentry'
    uid = Column(Integer, Sequence('ThingEntry_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.uid'))
    entity = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('thing'))

class Quu(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'quu'
    uid = Column(Integer, Sequence('Quu_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    description = Column(String)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "something"

class QuuEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'quuentry'
    uid = Column(Integer, Sequence('QuuEntry_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.uid'))
    entity = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('quu'))
```

What are some more concise ways of defining all these classes/tables? This method has a lot of code duplication/self-repeating.

I was thinking of some kind of inheritance so that I could bring that code down to

```
class Thing(Base):
    pass
class ThingEntry(Base):
    pass
class Quu(Base):
    description = Column(String)
class QuuEntry(Base):
    pass
```

With some magic auto-assigning the other values (`__tablename__`, `uid`, `foo`, etc), but I'm not sure if that's possible or optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at documentation about auto reflection http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/core/reflection.html

Answer (score -1):

Used a factory approach with metaclasses, as such:

```
class ObjectFactory:
    def __new__(cls, class_name, parents, attributes):
        attributes['__tablename__'] = class_name
        attributes['uid'] = Column(Integer, Sequence(class_name + '_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
        attributes['name'] = Column(String)

class EntryFactory:
    def __new__(cls, class_name, parents, attributes):
        attributes['__tablename__'] = class_name
        attributes['uid'] = Column(Integer, Sequence(class_name + '_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
        attributes['foo'] = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.uid'), nullable=False)
        attributes['entity_id'] = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(class_name[:-5]), nullable=False)

class Thing(Base, metaclass=ObjectFactory):
    pass
class ThingEntry(Base, metaclass=EntryFactory):
    pass
class Quu(Base, metaclass=ObjectFactory):
    description = Column(String)
class QuuEntry(Base, metaclass=EntryFactory):
    pass
```